# What does "have demonstration of something" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Has little to no understanding and demonstration of knowledge or
>   behavior

Does "demonstration" here mean an ability to perform something?
Or does this sentence mean that this knowledge or behavior hasn't been performed or little performed?

Comment: What was the source of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *demonstrate* something, or *have demonstration of* something, it means that you display those traits.

So this sentence would mean that (someone) doesn't understand and doesn't show that they understand.

I believe the reason for the down vote was the fact that this could be discovered with a quick Google search (first definition): https://www.google.com/search?q=demonstration&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS819US819&oq=demo&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60.2799j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8